# Зачем нужен метод revokeGplusAccess при регистрации через Google?

Tags: java, android, google-api

Я по примеру делаю гугл регистрацию и здесь указан метод, который можно вызвать после того как юзер залогинился вот он

```
/**
 * Revoking access from google
 */
private void revokeGplusAccess() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                        Log.e("pavan", "User access revoked!");
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Не могу понять что он делает? Кто может обьяснить? Если перевести, что написано, то он нужен для аннулирования доступа, но чем это отличается от LogOut тогда?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Этот метод, в отличие от log out, отвязывает приложение от Гугла, то есть - на серверах Гугла не будет информации о том что приложение имеет доступ к Гугл+ профилю.

Если сделать простой log out, приложение все еще будет связано с Google+, юзер сможет залогиниться и снова продолжить пользоваться интеграцией сервисов, когда потребуется

Comment: А зачем это используют? Чтоб забанить тех кто плохо себя ведет?

Comment: Есть много ситуаций, например - юзер больше не хочет чтобы апп имел доступ к его аккаунту (после отвязки он может выложить в G+ какую-то свежую информацию, которую не увидит апп).
Советую сделать кнопку "Отвязать аккаунт", помимо logout. В крупных приложениях (и на сайтах) такая опция обычно имеется

Comment: Ок спасибо! Можете еще подсказать пару вопросов... 1)То есть вы хотите сказать, что если юзер делает logout, то приложение все еще имеет доступ к его аккаунту? 2) А как потом юзер может залогиниться если примет снова такое решение? Он имеет эту возможность?

Comment: 1) Если сделать logout, Google все еще разрешает доступ приложения к G+, но приложение не сможет запросить у G+ ничего до тех пор пока юзер не залогинится.  
2) Юзер может залогиниться, выбрав аккаунт и введя пароль, как обычно. Если вопрос об воссоединении связки апп<->G+ после revokeAccess, юзеру не только придется залогиниться снова, но и снова разрешить доступ аппа к аккаунту G+

Comment: Я извиняюсь)) Но вот по ответу 1-му... Вы говорите, что G все еще разрешает доступ, но app не может ничего запросить... А что значит разрешает доступ? Вот смотри у меня яблоки есть можешь брать, но тебе нельзя... так?)) Просто до сих пор не пойму приниципиальной разницы... Если я сделал LogOut, то все... приложение ничего не получит с моего аккаунта... Зачем мне лепить 2-ю кнопку ? Вот я как юзер допустим... Передо мной 2 кнопки '1-я отключиться', '2-я полностью отключиться...' как я как юзер должен понять какую нажать?

Comment: Представим клуб. Можно зайти если ты в списке VIP и назвал свой пароль.  
Если выйти (logout) и зайти еще раз (логин), надо назвать имя и пароль чтобы впустили снова.
Вошел - твои данные узнали, все ок.  
А если сделать revokeAccess, тебя вычеркнут из списка VIP, и тогда - называй/не называй, все равно не впустят, но и данные о тебе сотрут.
Если надо, снова разрешаешь внести себя в список, и ты в VIP, можно делать логин :)  
Основная кнопка - `[выйти]`. После нее надо просто снова залогиниться.  
Спрятанная в настройках кнопка - `[отсоединить аккаунт]`, на всякий пожарный, если юзер захочет

Comment: Теперь понял)) Спасибо))